# Is this character in The Last Jedi a puppet, CGI, or a mixture of both?

Tags: character, production, film-techniques, star-wars, the-last-jedi

In *The Last Jedi*:

> An “old friend” (Yoda) appears in spirit form on Ahch-To and has a conversation with Luke.

I'm guessing that this character was a puppet, however the eyes in particular looked strange which makes me wonder whether it was CGI after all, or possibly a mixture of the two.

Are there any sources (yet) that confirm which approach was used?

Comment: Same question on the Sci-fi site: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176843/in-the-last-jedi-how-was-this-character-filmed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR: The character was a mixture of both - a puppet enhanced in post with CGI.**

---

Lighting company [Digital Sputnik](https://twitter.com/DigitalSputnik), which specializes in practical lighting effects used on movie productions, commented on a recent tweet that they have now illuminated both Jesus

> and Yoda.

Given that the company is fairly new, we can safely eliminate any of the older productions in which he appeared. This, along with a few other hints here & there, would seem to indicate that the character is indeed a practical puppet on-set.

In addition, Star Wars theorist Mike Zeroh [claims](https://www.express.co.uk/entertainment/films/836048/Star-Wars-8-The-Last-Jedi-leak-Yoda-Force-ghost-new-details-Frank-Oz) to have heard from a source at Pinewood Studios that a special set was constructed to accomodate

> the Yoda puppet speaking with Luke.

---

Update: Director Rian Johnson has now confirmed this during an [interview](http://uproxx.com/movies/rian-johnson-the-last-jedi/) with Uproxx...

> Neal Scanlan and his team did a recreation of the Yoda puppet. *It’s not only a puppet, it’s an exact replica of the Empire puppet.* They found the original molds for it. They found the woman that painted the original eyes for Yoda. Then Frank came and worked with them for a few weeks to get the puppet right. He did a lot of testing and a lot of adjusting with the puppet creators. It was amazing to watch the process.

**So the answer to your question would appear to be... a mixture of both.**